# How to remove axis from Google Charts using options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, bar-chart, google-visualization

Im trying to hide the Y axis values displayed on the right. Ive been looking though Google documentation but cant figure out what will allow me to do this. Im assuming if the option exists it will also hide the gridlines.

[image]

```
var options = {
      bars: 'vertical',
      series: {
        2: {targetAxisIndex:2},
        3: {targetAxisIndex:3},
        4: {targetAxisIndex:4}, 
        5: {targetAxisIndex:5} 
      },
      axes: {
        x: {
          0: { side: 'top', label: ''} // Top x-axis.
        }
      },
      vAxis: {viewWindowMode: 'pretty'},
      height: 400,
      width: 900
    };
var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('ocGraph'));
chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out,

```
 var options = {
 bars: 'vertical',
 series: {
    2: {targetAxisIndex:2},
    3: {targetAxisIndex:3},
    4: {targetAxisIndex:4}, 
    5: {targetAxisIndex:5} 
 },
 axes: {
        x: {
          0: { side: 'top', label: ''} // Top x-axis.
        },
        y: {
          2: { side: 'top' , label: ''},
          3: { side: 'top', label: ''},
          4: { side: 'top' , label: ''},
          5: { side: 'top' , label: ''}
        }
      },
      vAxis: {viewWindowMode: 'pretty'},
      vAxes: {
        2: {
         gridlines: { count:0},
         ticks: [0],
         textStyle: {fontSize: 0}
        },
        3: {
         gridlines: { count:0},
         ticks: [0],
         textStyle: {fontSize: 0}
        },
        4: {
         gridlines: { count:0},
         ticks: [0],
         textStyle: {fontSize: 0}
        },
        5: {
         gridlines: { count:0},
         ticks: [0],
         textStyle: {fontSize: 0}
        }
      },
```